# Agregar condición números negativos a expresión regular

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente expresión regular que es justamente lo que necesito, permitir escribir números con máximo 2 decimales, pero también es necesario que permita escribir números negativos, no conozco mucho sobre expresiones regulares y he hecho algunos intentos pero no funcionan

```
^\d{1,10}(\.\d{0,2})*(,\d+)?$
```

Esa es la expresión regular, he intentado agregando la expresión para números negativos pero al parecer la tengo incorrecta

```
^\d-?[1-10]+[1,10](\.\d{0,2})*(,\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente el unico cambio que le hecho es poner `-?` antes de `\d` en el inicio de la expresion regular.

```js
const regex = /^-?\d{1,10}(\.\d{0,2})*(,\d+)?$/;

console.log(regex.test(-2.5));
```

Donde `-?` significa:

Coincide con el caracter `-` de manera opcional (puede o no estar presente).